# python file open through io.wrapper error

Tags: python

I have an array of files names I need to loop through, perform some operation on them then write out the file. The issue I'm running into is on the file(open). When I loop through the file names it appears the library expatbuilder.py is not happy. Not sure what it is complaining about. I printed out the file name, before the open, `5c6d9523579f27109567843b.xml`

its correct, but after I try the file open the name comes back as: 
`io.TextIOWrapper name = (filename I'm trying to open) mode=r encoding=cp1252`

and of course croaks. Any assistance in helping me decode this issue and a solution would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Searched the internet for a solution.

```
fileArry = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):  
    for filename in files:
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            fileArry.append(filename)

for i in range(len(fileArry)):
 #print (fileArry[i])
 datasource = open(fileArry[i])
 #print (datasource)
 doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(datasource)  # parse an open file
```

I expected each file name to open and then be processed. The filename before the open is correct, it, well for the lack of a better word, gets mangled by I believe the file open method.

`io.TextIOWrapper name =`

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Complete error is: io.TextIOWrapper name=(filename trying to open) mode=r  encoding = cp1252

Comment: Complete error is: io.TextIOWrapper name=(filename trying to open) mode=r  encoding = cp1252 and then: File xmlAnon.py line # in module  doc=xml.minidom.parse(datasource) and one more: minidom.py line 1958 in parse return expatbuilder.parse(file) and a couple of other lines in expatbuilder.py line 913 and line 207 in parser.parse(buffer, 0) with xml.parsers.expat ExpatError; syntax error: line 1, column 0

Comment: What I believe the issue is, is the filename passed into the open method. If I look at the file name before the open, it looks just fine. When the open gets to it, it has all that extraneous info in it -- io.TextIOWrapper name=(filename to open) mode = r encoding=cp1252.  The question is, how do I get just the filenname passed into the open method? Where is the io.TextIOWrapper string coming from? Can I strip that info away to just get to the filename?

Comment: got rid of the io.TextIOWrapper errror, managed to parse out the file name and pass it to the open. But, I'm still getting the errors. Kicks off with a line from my code doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(datasource) then the next line is coming from minidom.py line 1958, in parse, next line is return expatbuilder.parse(file)  followed on the next line by expatbuilder.py line 913 in parse result = builder.parsefile(file) followed by another expatbuilder.py error line 207 in parsefile, parser.parse(buffer, 0) and finally, the last line is xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error, line 1 column 0